# $save on child objects gives error

Tags: firebase

I'm running a code similar to the following with AngularFire

```
current = $firebase(URL);

current.$on('loaded', function() {
  typeof current.users == 'object'  // current.users is a dict
  current.users[uid] = {
    'some': 'data'
  };
  return current.$save('users/<uid>');
});
```

Throws "Error: Firebase.set failed: First argument contains undefined" after the `$save` line.

Is it possible to directly save a child item? 
If not, what would be the best option if I don't want to load `current.users` with `$firebase`?

Answer (score 0):

`$save` can only take a single string i.e. one child deep. If you want to save items deeper down the child list, you'll have to first create references using `$child` instead (which does accept strings with '/' separators in them).

You are already loading everything at URL by calling `current = $firebase(URL)` - if you want to avoid loading the users list, then I would create a reference directly at users/UID:

```js
currentUser = $firebase(URL + '/users/<uid>');
currentUser.$set({'some': 'data'});
```